# .NET: Is there a way to see the pure http request sent using HttpClient?

Tags: .net, rest, http, httpclient

I am using .NET 4.8 and make a HttpClient.GetAsync() call to a external endpoint.

Is there a way to inspect the pure http request with all header information sent to the http endpoint?

Thank you.